# condition check for enter number would be betwen 0 to 9 0r decimal "."

Tags: android

i have a edit text box in which i can enter alphanumeric charracter but when i click the summit button then a checking would be perform for either edit text contains values 0 to 9 and also it can contain "." and in other case it will show a message that "pls enter numeric values" so how to achive it?
means validate 0123456789 and "." in edit textbox

```
   public void onClick(View arg0) {






                String Ammount =
                        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.price))
                          .getText().toString();

              double db = Math.ceil(Integer.parseInt(Ammount)*100)/100;
              ammount = Double.toString(db);

            }};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why to go hard just don't allow to enter string in your xml add:

```
<EditText
....

android:inputType="numberDecimal"
...
```

/>

Answer (score 1):

add this tag in its xml `android:numeric = "decimal"`

Answer (score 1):

One of the option would be use regex. Show the error message when `validate` return false.

```
    boolean validate(String s )
   {
      return s.matches("[0-9\\.]*");
   }
```